# Pegar tamanho do elemento de um vetor?

Tags: c

Tenho um vetor assim:
`int nums[10] + {1235, 14627, 1625161, 54437};`

Sempre o elemento será maior ou igual a 1000, ou seja, com comprimento igual a 4, podendo se estender ate 10 algarismos. Quero saber como pego o comprimento desses números inteiros do meu vetor. Ou seja, usando o vetor de exemplo, tenho o primeiro elemento que tem 4, outros com 5, 7 e 5 respectivamente. Mas como faço para pegar o comprimento pelo código?

Comment: Votei como duplicata pois as duas perguntas estão intimamente relacionadas - não dá pra responder à outra sem responder a essa também. Além disso, por "tamanho do elemento" você quer dizer "número de dígitos decimais". Você poderia definir "tamanho" de outras formas também (na memória, todos os elementos têm o mesmo tamanho - são inteiros de 32 bits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim de repente vejo duas maneiras: convertendo para string ou usando a função `log()`.

```
#include <string.h> // para strlen()

int nums[] = {1235, 14627, 1625161, 54437};
for (int k = 0; k < sizeof nums / sizeof *nums; k++) {
    char tmp[12];
    sprintf(tmp, "%d", nums[k]);
    printf("O numero %d tem comprimento %d.\n", nums[k], (int)strlen(tmp));
}
```

ou

```
#include <math.h> // para log()

int nums[] = {1235, 14627, 1625161, 54437};
for (int k = 0; k < sizeof nums / sizeof *nums; k++) {
    printf("O numero %d tem comprimento %d.\n", nums[k], (int)log10(nums[k]) + 1);
}
```